# newbie mistake? JSON and Ember

Tags: ember.js

new here to ember, and very much trying to learn - and learn where I'm going wrong.

I'm being fed json that looks like this:

```
"status": "success",
  "data": {
    "groups": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test1234",
        "kind": "Happy",
        "parent_group_id": 1,
        "children_count": {
         "boy": 10,
         "girl": 4,
         "pets": 2
        },
        "is_top_level": true
      },
```

The path to get this info would be /api/groups/top.

I have a (what I believe would be) simple app.js:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {             
  this.route("login", {path: "/"});     
  this.route("groups");
    this.resource('about');
 });

App.GroupsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
     return App.Group.find('top');
}

});

App.LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
login: function(username, password){
        jQuery.ajax({
           url: "/api/auth",
            type: 'post',
                data: JSON.stringify( { "username": "user", "password": "pass" } ),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            if (result.status === 'success') {
                    user = result.data.user;
                    App.User.id = user.id;
                    App.User.name = user.name;

                    App.User.isAuthenticated = true;
                    App.User.displayUnits = "F";
                                } else {
                    //debugger;
                    throw "The! username and/or password you have entered is incorrect, please try again ";
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, errorOut) {
                throw "The? username and/or password you have entered is incorrect, please try   again ";
            return false;
            }
        });
        if (App.User.isAuthenticated)
            this.transitionToRoute('groups');
    }}
});

App.RESTAdapter = RL.RESTAdapter.create({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  namespace: 'api/'
});

App.Client = RL.Client.create({
  adapter: App.RESTAdapter
});

App.User = RL.Model.extend({
    username: RL.attr('string'),
      id: RL.attr('string'),
      isAuthenticated: RL.attr('boolean'),
    });

App.Group = RL.Model.extend({
    id: RL.attr('string'),
    name: RL.attr('string'),
    kind: RL.attr('string')
    });

App.RESTAdapter = RL.RESTAdapter.create({
  defaultData: { cookie: "data"}
});
```

I'm trying to display each "group" in my template. For example {{#each groups}} {{name}} {{/each}}, but no luck - I can see the JSON data in the response in inspector, and no errors - but still, nothing coming trough.

Any help?

Thanks!

Ptep

***edit - template:***

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars">

        {{outlet}}
      </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="groups">
            <h3>Hello, 
              {{#each groups}}

              {{name}}! <br>
              {{kind}}, {{id}}
             {{/each}}
                        </h3>

</script>
```

Comment: Is groups a property on the model being returned by `App.Group.find('top')`?  Like if I were to do `var j = App.Group.find('top');` and we pretend it returned the model right away would `j.groups` be a property with a collection on it?  (or if it's a promise `j.then(function(result){result.groups a property?});`

Comment: Adding your template would be helpful as well

Comment: Groups would be a collection of different connected records - Test1234, has an id of 2, parent id of 1, has 10 boys, etc... and  then another - Test5678, id of 3, parent id of 1, has 2 boys, etc...

Comment: I understand what groups should be, but is there actually a property on your model called groups.  Looking at your json, I'd guess there was a property called `data.groups` or I'd guess your adapter parsed out the individual groups and returned an array of group objects on it.  See the answer, I don't want to put it in the comment

Comment: I think I see what you mean... No, there isn't a property called groups.

Comment: were you able to get it working? or are you still fighting it?

Comment: Still fighting it. I think my problem is what you hinted at, that the data I'm trying to reach is embedded under "data" and then "groups". Or maybe I'm wrong there.

Comment: Getting "Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. You passed '<App.Group:ember347>' (wrapped in (generated index controller))" with listed answer...

Comment: Just got it. Thanks for your help - put me on the right path with data.groups....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array itself would be the context of your template, so you would either use

```
{{#each}}{{name}}{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each model}}{{name}}{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each controller}}{{name}}{{/each}}
```

or

```
{{#each item in controller}}{{item.name}}{{/each}}
```